# java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 25 failed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao

I am trying to create a android app using GreenDAO, this is ERP kind of project so practically it is not possible to post all code here, but i am going to share only related code

```
    QueryBuilder<PartyCommunication> partyCommQueryBuilder = partyCommunicationDao.queryBuilder();
   partyCommQueryBuilder = partyCommQueryBuilder.where(
        PartyCommunicationDao.Properties.CommType.eq("ALERT"), 
        PartyCommunicationDao.Properties.ReferenceCategory.eq("Low Stock"));
   List<PartyCommunication> listOfPartyComm = partyCommQueryBuilder.list();

   PartyCommunication daoPartyCommunication = listItr.next();
   Long reference_entity_key = daoPartyCommunication.getReferenceEntityKey();       
   Product product = daoSessionUni.getProductDao().load(reference_entity_key);
   ProductDetail productDetail = new ProductDetail(product);
   Integer inventoryQOH= productDetail.getInventoryQOH();
```

I am getting exception in this line

```
  Product product = daoSessionUni.getProductDao().load(reference_entity_key);
```

When i debug our application i found that it throwing exception from one of our DAO class as below

```
         public Product readEntity(Cursor cursor, int offset) {
    Product entity = new Product( //
        .
        .
        .
        .
        cursor.getShort(offset + 23) != 0, // isSync
        cursor.getShort(offset + 24) != 0, // isDeleted
        cursor.getString(offset + 25), // createdBy
        cursor.getString(offset + 26), // modifiedBy
        cursor.isNull(offset + 27) ? null : new java.util.Date(cursor.getLong(offset + 27)), // lastSyncTime
        new java.util.Date(cursor.getLong(offset + 28)), // created
        new java.util.Date(cursor.getLong(offset + 29)) // modified
    );
    return entity;
}
```

In this line

```
  cursor.getString(offset + 25), // createdBy
```

This is our 25th column of table.I know that all code is not enough to understand what is going wrong and why i am getting this exception , so i am also going to post logcat output

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 25 failed
at net.sqlcipher.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
at net.sqlcipher.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:382)
at net.sqlcipher.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
at com.tarnea.kareeb.model.ProductDao.readEntity(ProductDao.java:273)
at com.tarnea.kareeb.model.ProductDao.readEntity(ProductDao.java:1)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.loadCurrent(AbstractDao.java:417)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.loadUnique(AbstractDao.java:163)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.loadUniqueAndCloseCursor(AbstractDao.java:150)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.load(AbstractDao.java:139)
at com.tarnea.android.DataCleaningService.adjustLowStockAlertTable(DataCleaningService.java:115)
at com.tarnea.sync.kareeb.pharma.syncadapter.SyncManager.performSync(SyncManager.java:970)
at com.tarnea.sync.kareeb.pharma.syncadapter.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:96)
at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:254
```

Thanks in advance to all.If anybody have some interest to solve my problem then please please ask any further information whatever you want.

Comment: Show the query for the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I update my question. Please have a look and help me.

Comment: @CL....Any idea what is wrong with above code...??

Comment: I don't know anything about the internals of GreenDAO. But why do you think that the cursor has 25 columns?

Comment: Because this is our DB schema....

Comment: Is `offset` representing the row in your `ResultSet`?
If so, you should be using `Cursor.move(int offset)` or `Cursor.moveToNext()` instead. `Cursor.getShort()` takes the number of the column in a single row.

Comment: offset represent column of our table

Comment: @CL... I got one cause but i am not sure can you suggest me..it is correct or not...??

Comment: Do you have defined `Property`s of all those columns?

Comment: yes...        public final static Property CreatedBy = new Property(25, String.class, "createdBy", false, "created_by");

Comment: Did you check, if the databasefile that you are actually using has all columns you expect? I worked a lot with greendao and I also know the most important internals of it. Such errors alway are based in incorrect, forgotten or non-working schema-updates. (see my answer)

Comment: @AlexS... Thanks alex... and sorry for late replay.. I will check it and .. Let you know...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the query. The SQLite-Table simply does only contain 24 columns.

Probably you modified your database schema by adding new columns like `createdBy`.

1. Either you forgot to update your db using `OpenHelper`
2. Or you had an error in your `ALTER TABLE`-statements
3. Or you ran your app with the new schema-version but without your `ALTER TABLE`-statements yet included (which is practically the same as 1.

Have a look at your database using SqliteManager, to verify your tables have the columns you expect.

If you cannot get your database-file you can simply delete your app with all data or increase your schema-version and use the `DevOpenHelper` to recreate the whole database.